# Latex Beamer GET background color

Tags: beamer

For the purpose of blurring the current frame in my latex beamer presentation, I use a `pgfinterruptboundingbox` like this:

```
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
     \fill <2> [fill=white, opacity=0.85] (0,-2) rectangle (10.5, 5);
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
```

However, due to the `fill=white` the slide is not only shaded, but whitened.

[image]

So I thought I could use the canvas background color to fill instead. However, I could not find how to access the color variable, like e.g. `canvas.bg` or alike.

How to access these colors?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The metropolis theme is a bit strange. Instead of in the background canvas, the colour is stored in `normal text.bg`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
     \fill[fill=normal text.bg] (0,-2) rectangle (10.5, 5);
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

However if you want to combine it with opacity, you need a lighter colour, otherwise the colour from the transparency and the normal background will sum to a darker colour:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
     \fill[fill=normal text.bg!85, opacity=0.85] (0,-2) rectangle (10.5, 5);
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you for your help. 

Follow up: Where did you find the information on the theme, like `normal text.bg`?

Comment: @MoritzFischer-Gundlach Reading the themes .sty files https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer-contrib/themes/metropolis/source. If this theme would behave like normal beamer themes, then one could guess most if the names, but metropolis is a bit strange....

Comment: Why not just use the  `bg` color?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, you are actually back ^^. By the way, if I am not mistaken the `background canvas` style is normally a child of `normal text`, so in which way is the Metropolis theme strange ?

Comment: @BambOo No, not back. I answered this on Stackoverflow, not here. If most of the other themes use the background canvas, then the one theme which does use something else is the strange one.

Comment: @BambOo Also I'm not a big fan of setting the background colour via `normal text.bg` because this will also change all other elements like blocks etc.